# Errors with mongo-community6 on mac cannot start

Tags: mongodb

I am having these issues with mongo startup on mac.  There are two.  One when I start without sudo and one with sudo.  Setup with brew.

brew install mongodb-community@6.0

Tried: sudo brew services restart mongodb-community

Without sudo, permission denied error.

{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-10T14:01:32.755-05:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"}}

With sudo

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-10T13:55:50.382-05:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20573,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Wrong mongod version","attr":{"error":"UPGRADE PROBLEM: Found an invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document (ERROR: Location4926900: Invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document in admin.system.version: { _id: \"featureCompatibilityVersion\", version: \"4.2\" }. See https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/5.0-compatibility/#feature-compatibility. :: caused by :: Invalid feature compatibility version value, expected '5.0' or '5.3' or '6.0. See https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/5.0-compatibility/#feature-compatibility.). If the current featureCompatibilityVersion is below 5.0, see the documentation on upgrading at https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/5.0/#upgrade-procedures."}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-10T13:5
```

Comment: Looks like two issues, still couldn't run as non root for some reason, even working on that directory.  And looked like older files I didn't see, deleted the older files.  That other deleted answer was correct.

Comment: Did you try to upgrade an existing MongoDB? If yes, then you can upgrade only from version 5. If you run a lower version, e.g. version 4 then you must first upgrade to version 5 before you can upgrade to version 6.